# ImageEx in ListView freezes UIThread

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

> **uwp-community-toolkit  version2.2**

I've got a couple of ImageEx element inside my listview which they are bind to urls. So when I launch my application it seems like UI thread is blocked by ImageEx. I cannot move app window, resize window, scroll the list or interact with another part of the application till all the ImageEx images are loaded from the Internet.

I wanna know if this is the normal behavior or not?! And if there is a way to fix the problem?!

My ListViewItem Template:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="m:RepoModel">
   <controls:ImageEx x:Phase="3"
        IsCacheEnabled="True"
        Source="{x:Bind owner.avatar_url}"
        Height="125" Width="125"                                       
        PlaceholderSource="ms-appx:///Assets/pl.png"/>
```

Comment: This should be fixed in the 3.0 release. Can you try testing with the latest dev build: https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/uwpcommunitytoolkit

Comment: @ShawnKendrot well I was using the stable version. I will try 3.0-preview version and i will update here if things were okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shawn Kendrot mentioned, they have fixed it on `uwp-community-toolkit version3.0` and I just test the stable version and I can approve that

Answer (score 0):

> The [`ImageEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/imageex) control downloads images asynchronously, while showing a loading indicator. Source images are then stored in the application's local cache to preserve resources and load time.

For my test, if you enable `IsCacheEnabled` property, you will not resize windows fluently. Because there are a lot of I/O operation that cause UI freeze when the image is cached.

If you want to resize windows fluently during loading image, you could disable
 `IsCacheEnabled` property.